# Having trouble setting up API call using array of parameters

Tags: php, get, rapidshare

I am building a class to send API calls to Rapidshare and return the results of said call. Here's how I want the call to be done:

```
$rs = new rs();

$params = array(
    'sub'   =>  'listfiles_v1',
    'type'  =>  'prem',
    'login' =>  '10347455',
    'password'  =>  'not_real_pass',
    'realfolder'    => '0',
    'fields'    => 'filename,downloads,size',
    );

print_r($rs->apiCall($params));
```

And here's the class so far:

```
class RS
{
    var $baseUrl = 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=';

    function apiCall($params)
    {
        $newUrl = $baseUrl;
        $keys = array_keys($params);
        $count = count($params);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $newUrl .= $keys[$i];
            $newUrl .= '&';
            $newUrl .= $params[$keys[$i]];
        }
        return $newUrl;
    }
}
```

Obviously i'm returning `$newUrl` and using `print_r()` to test the query string, and this is what it comes out as with the code shown above:

```
sub&listfiles_v1type&premlogin&10347455password&_not_real_passrealfolder&0fields&filename,downloads,size
```

When it should be:

```
http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=listfiles_v1&type=prem&login=10347455&password=not_real_pass&realfolder=0&fields=filename,downloads,size
```

Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do here :P It's probably a silly mistake that I'm failing to find or a logical error.

Answer (score 1):

You should have:

```
$newUrl = $this->baseUrl;
```

You need to use `$this` to refer to members of that class from within that class. Also don't use `var` to declare members. It's PHP4 and (afaik) deprecated. Instead use `private` (etc.

Lastly, your loop to create the parameters can be greatly simplified and the logic isn't correct for what you want to achieve. Try:

```
class RS {
  private $baseUrl = 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?';

  function apiCall($params) {
    $newUrl = $this->baseUrl;
    foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
      $newUrl .= urlencode($k) . '=' . urlencode($v) . '&';
    }
    return $newUrl;
  }
}
```

Or, even better, use [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
class RS {
  private $baseUrl = 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?';

  function apiCall($params) {
    return $this->baseUrl . http_build_query($params);
  }
}
```